# Why is Ask Ubuntu set up to discourage users from participating?

Tags: discussion, support

For a while now I have noticed Ask Ubuntu has a system of PFO in place. The system I have experienced does not allow me to post or answer questions unless I have 50 reputation points. The system suggests I should answer some questions in order to get a reputation.

Your system looks like it is here to serve egos instead of helping.

Please correct me if I am misinformed.

Comment: What is "PFO" in "askUbuntu has a system of PFO in place"?

Comment: Is it something like "Please F*#k Off"?

Answer (score 11):

Firstly, regarding comments, the number of comments provided by people who have not had time to acclimate to how the site works that were *bad comments* or not even necessary comments or were otherwise poor or ranty or against the rules led the owners to require 50 rep to curb comment spam.  It's ***very easy*** to get 50 reputation provided you actually take the time to put good effort into asking questions and answering them.

---

However, of a more important note here is the quality of your answers - or rather, the lack thereof.

Taking a look at your account, you've encountered the 'Answering Ban" which blocks you from answering questions.  You can still ask questions, though.

Firstly, you need to read up here: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

***READ THIS IN ITS ENTIRETY.***  Then take note of the following:

Of your four answers:

- One was not actually an answer and incorrectly stated that there are problems installing and running Skype on 16.04 - the issues your answer referred to were *not* related to OP's problem, meaning your post was not an answer (and was deleted from the review queue).
- The second of your answers was simply an "I'm having the same problem", and making a note that something about installing something with `sudo make install` would actually help the problem.  This wasn't the case.  Also not an answer (and deleted from review)
- The third of your answers was ranting about your post being deleted from the review queue by multiple individuals.  This is not an answer and not permitted, and was removed for that reason.
- Your fourth answer was simply "This is garbage, so my solution is to throw this away and use a six-dollar adapter".  Also not an answer per the guidelines we have for good quality answers.

The answering ban is the system doing automated quality control - you've posted 4 answers, of which **every single answer** has been deleted by the review queues or by moderators because they were either against the rules or did not meet the quality requirements, and/or were flagged as such.

As such, the **system** is disallowing you from answering posts as a measure of automated quality control.  You need to provide ***POSITIVE*** contributions in other methods or the system will not remove the answering ban.

As for *asking questions*, you can still post questions so long as they abide by the rules of the site.